# How to Get StrikeOnText Effect in a table view while enable the edit option using xcode4.3 & above?

Tags: xcode4.5, tableview, strikethrough, rowdeleting

[image: Stike through effect]

```
How to get Strike Text Animation while we select edit option for the table view
and also when we swipe on a table row.We need to get this type of style before deleting!
```

**I want in xcode4.5**

> Please help me out by providing suggestions and posts and it will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [strikethroughlabel library](https://github.com/shodgin/StrikeThroughLabel) has property to set text as strike through.

You could just switch it on and off based on table view editing state